# How to uncompress in java gzip file with LZMA compression

Tags: java, gzip, lzma

I need to uncompress in java a gzip file that is compressed with LZMA. Here http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=12065 explains that they do it passing to a lzma decode raw data function the data that starts in offset 14 that starts with the byte 5D.

I have downloaded 7zip SDK, but I didn´t find a way to achieve it.
So I need to find a library in java that allows me to do what they do in that link.

Here I uploaded the file if someone want´s to try to decompress it in java:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C84F192CB5EEBC9!714&authkey=!ANbGTpAwTzw5FaA&ithint=file%2cbin

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/gziplzma2 doesn't work

Comment: changed to https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C84F192CB5EEBC9!714&authkey=!ANbGTpAwTzw5FaA&ithint=file%2cbin

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it with SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder passing as properties the first 5 bytes;
and the calling the method  code.